# SpringBoot + MongoDB "Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'"

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

I am new to Spring Boot, following tutorials to create a simple restAPI using MongoDB, and I keep encountering this same error " `Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'` My db is hosted on atlas.

**GroceryItem**

```
package com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.models;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "grocery-item")
public class GroceryItem {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private String category;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GroceryItem [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", quantity=" + quantity + ", category=" + category + "]";
    }
}
```

**ItemRepository**

```
package com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.repository;

import com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.models.GroceryItem;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<GroceryItem, String> {
}
```

**ItemService**

```
package com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.service;

import com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.models.GroceryItem;

public interface ItemService {
    String save (GroceryItem item);
}
```

**ItemServiceImpl**

```
package com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.service;

import com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.models.GroceryItem;
import com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.repository.ItemRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;
    @Override
    public String save(GroceryItem item) {
        return itemRepository.save(item).getId();
    }
}
```

**ItemController**

```
package com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.controller;

import com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.models.GroceryItem;
import com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.service.ItemService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/item")
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    @PostMapping
    public String save(@RequestBody GroceryItem item){
        return itemService.save(item);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.github.nohgo</groupId>
    <artifactId>GroceryList</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GroceryList</name>
    <description>GroceryList</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>annotationProcessor</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=GroceryList
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://username:password@grocery-list.6iphtjn.mongodb.net/
spring.data.mongodb.database=mygrocerylist

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

From here I expected to be able to launch my VM and start sending a post request to my api, but instead I am getting this error on startup (only posted a line because block was marked as spam)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'itemController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'itemService': Error creating bean with name 'itemServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'itemRepository': Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository' defined in com.github.nohgo.grocerylist.repository.ItemRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
```

I know this error is likely just me making some stupid mistake but I am unable to see where I deviate from these tutorials. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

**GroceryListApplication**

```
package com.github.nohgo.grocerylist;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GroceryListApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GroceryListApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your "main" application class - i.e. the starting point for the Spring Boot application, in particular include its package declaration.  Also do you have any Mongo configuration classes you have not shown?

Comment: @AndrewL whoops thought I had that, added. I don't have any other Mongo configuration files. I was under the impression that spring handled that with my provided URI, don't know if that impression is wrong.

Comment: Good: your SpringBoot class looks correctly annotated and a common gotcha is that it is at the wrong level (package scanning *which starts by default from this class* doesn't look at classes higher up in the hierarchy) .  But that looks all ok.

You are correct that you don't need any configuration classes. The default behaviour should work. 

Next hunch: take out the `mongodb-driver-sync` dependency.  `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` already includes an appropriately versioned mongo dependency.  Perhaps the `5.0.0` one is incompatible...

Comment: @AndrewL Unfortunately that didn't work, good to know that I don't need that in my dependency list though. Also some more background information I forgot to include - I built this project first just using a basic repository and command line runner application class and encountered the same issue. Don't know if that helps narrow it down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Basically that's the issue of dependencies you have used.

For that please replace the below dependencies from pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

with this

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
        <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo</artifactId>
        <version>6.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

please let me know if still issue persist, thanks!